# Compare two worksheets according to a column, compile a new worksheet showing the differences

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare two worksheets, say worksheet A and worksheet B.
Worksheet A looks like
[image]

whereas worksheet B looks like

[image]

In both sheets, column A is the unique correspondence between the two sheets, meaning that R1Oo1 in sheet A corresponds to R1Oo1 in sheet B. What I need to do is create a third sheet, let say sheet C, which should be as follows:

[image]

Basically, it should contain all the existing unique ID, so I was thinking about creating a collection or a dictionary and building a function finding the correspondences between the two sheets. This is my first start, there are maybe lots of mistakes, but I think the rationale could be right.

```
Sub find()
    Dim wb as Workbook, ws_A as Worksheets, ws_B as Worksheets
    Dim matches as Collection
    Dim myrange_A as Range, myrange_B as Range, cell_A as Range

    Set ws_A = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws_B = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set myrange_A = ws_A.Range("A2",ws_A.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set myrange_B = ws_B.Range("A2",ws_B.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    For Each cell_A in myrange_A
        Set matches = FindID(myrange_B, cell_A.Value)
        If matches.count > 0 Then 'it finds the correspondence (which can be at most 1)
           '... 'here I should tell the code to add one more line in the worksheet C
        Else
           'in this case there are no correspondences, and the line should be created too in the sheet C
       End If
    Next  'go to the next cell of the range

    'here I need to to the same starting from myrange_B 
End Sub
```

FindID is a function, defined as follows

```
Public Function FindID(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection

   Dim newcoll As New Collection, f As Range, addr As String
   Set f = rng.find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
       LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
       SearchDirection:= xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
   If Not (f is Nothing) Then addr = f.Address() 'store first correspondence found
   Do Until f is Nothing
       newcoll.Add f
       Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
       If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do 'exit if it looped back to cell 1
   Loop
   Set FindID = newcoll

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Unique Data Using a Dictionary

```
Sub CopyUniqueData()
    
    ' Write the values from the ranges to arrays and put the arrays
    ' into a collection.
    
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    
    Dim sws1 As Worksheet: Set sws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = sws1 _
        .Range("A2:B" & sws1.Range("A" & sws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    coll.Add rg1.Value
    
    Dim sws2 As Worksheet: Set sws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = sws2 _
        .Range("A2:B" & sws2.Range("A" & sws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    coll.Add rg2.Value
    
    ' Loop through the values in the arrays of the collection and write
    ' the unique values (first occurrences) of the second column
    ' to the keys of dictionaries created as items of the corresponding
    ' unique keys of the main dictionary.
    
    ' Its keys are the unique values of the first column.
    ' Its each item is a dictionary whose keys are holding
    ' the corresponding unique values of the second column.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim Key1 As Variant
    Dim Key2 As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim drCount As Long
    
    For Each Item In coll
        For r = 1 To UBound(Item, 1)
            Key1 = Item(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key1) Then ' exclude error values
                If Len(Key1) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                    If Not dict.Exists(Key1) Then
                        Set dict(Key1) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                        dict(Key1).CompareMode = vbTextCompare
                    End If
                    Key2 = Item(r, 2)
                    If Not dict(Key1).Exists(Key2) Then
                        dict(Key1)(Key2) = Empty
                        drCount = drCount + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    Next Item
                    
    If drCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values or blanks
    
    Set coll = Nothing ' the data is in the dictionary
                    
    ' Loop through the values of the dictionaries of the dictionary
    ' and write them to an array.
                    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    r = 0
    
    For Each Key1 In dict.Keys
        For Each Key2 In dict(Key1).Keys
            r = r + 1
            Data(r, 1) = Key1
            Data(r, 2) = Key2
        Next Key2
    Next Key1
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the destination range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    
    With dws.Range("A2").Resize(, 2)
        .Resize(drCount).Value = Data
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Unique data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain me the rationale behind the creation of dictionaries of dictionary?

Comment: The dictionary is convenient because its `keys` cannot contain two same items (strings) i.e. they are unique which you achieve by using `Exists`. There may be several fruits associated with each `key` so you need a data structure to keep track of that, too. You are actually searching for unique column pairs i.e. for `R1Oo1` there is `Apple` in `A` and there is `Apple` in `B`. To not write it twice, you write it to another dictionary which is held by the corresponding `Item` again to avoid duplicates. You could write the fruits to a comma-delimited string but how will you check for duplicates?